# In Vue.js project, I can not get the correct multiplication result

Tags: vue.js

In my vue.js project, the number * 100 get wrong number.

In my template:

```
<div class="res-show">
  总共折点: <span style="color:#ed3f14">{{ discount_point_total }}</span> <br>
  相当于折扣掉总价: <span>{{discount_point_total * 100}}%</span>
</div>
```

in my script:

```
export default{
    data(){
      return {
        discount_point_total:0.022
        ...
```

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alternatively, use [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

```
<span>{{ (discount_point_total*100).toFixed(2) }}%</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

The float point number precision lost, you can use this method to avoid the issue:

```
<span>{{ Math.round(discount_point_total * 100 * 100) / 100 }}%</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use toFixed
   {{ (0.022*100).toFixed(2) }}%

Note that the return value of this method is a string. Remember parseFloat when you use it. You need to know more about the foundation of ECMA Script.